# Cannot create Jupyter Notebook in HDInsight 4.0

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I'm using Azure HDInsight 4.0 (Spark 2.4).  When I attempt to create a new Jupyter notebook (Spark, but I get a similar error for PySpark notebooks), I get the following error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 457, in wrapper result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs)) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run value = future.result() File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result raise_exc_info(self._exc_info) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1021, in run yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 216, in post yield self._new_untitled(path, type=type, ext=ext) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1015, in run value = future.result() File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 237, in result raise_exc_info(self._exc_info) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 285, in wrapper yielded = next(result) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 171, in _new_untitled model = yield gen.maybe_future(self.contents_manager.new_untitled(path=path, type=type, ext=ext)) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 338, in new_untitled return self.new(model, path) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 364, in new model = self.save(model, path) File "/var/lib/.jupyter/jupyterazure/jupyterazure/httpfscontentsmanager.py", line 84, in save self.create_checkpoint(path) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 459, in create_checkpoint return self.checkpoints.create_checkpoint(self, path) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/checkpoints.py", line 79, in create_checkpoint model = contents_mgr.get(path, content=True) File "/var/lib/.jupyter/jupyterazure/jupyterazure/httpfscontentsmanager.py", line 56, in get 'metadata': {}}) File "/var/lib/.jupyter/jupyterazure/jupyterazure/model.py", line 45, in create_model_from_blob nbformat.version_info[0]) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 75, in reads nb = convert(nb, as_version) File "/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/converter.py", line 54, in convert "version doesn't exist" % (to_version)) ValueError: Cannot convert notebook to v5 because that version doesn't exist`

After this, a new notebook *does* appear on the home screen, but if I try to open it I get the following popup message:

```
An unknown error occurred while loading this notebook. This version can load notebook formats v4 or earlier. See the server log for details.
```

I can create a notebook just fine on an otherwise-identical HDI 3.6 cluster, but not on 4.0.  (I need 4.0 because I need to use Spark 2.4.)

Has anyone experienced/resolved this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, we have seen couple of questions on the same issue. You may follow the below steps to resolve the issue.

**Steps to resolve this issue:**

**Step1:** Connect to headnode via ssh and change content of file - `/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/_version.py`, replace **5** to **4**.

[image]

Change this to:

> version_info = (4, 0, 3)

[image]

**Step2:** Restart Jupyter service via Ambari.

[image]

For more details, refer [HDInshight Create not create Jupyter notebook](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c763fb4-79a9-496f-a75c-44a125e934ac/hdinshight-create-not-create-jupyter-notebook?forum=hdinsight#4e9cf0cf-78c7-4a0d-95f5-d4c40c6f4727)

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Comment: This worked, thank you!  Glad to see it's now in the documentation.

Comment: This issue has now been fixed in the Azure HDI service, so you should no longer see the error.